# Are these emojis valid UTF-8?

Tags: utf-8, vlc, dbus

#### Problem

When present in media file metadata, the following emojis (and presumably many others as well) cause VLC to crash. This appears to be due to dbus message validation rejecting them as invalid UTF-8 sequences. However, the iconv utility accepts them. Are they invalid, or is dbus at fault here?

```
 -> 0xf0 0x9f 0x94 0x88
 -> 0xf0 0x9f 0x8e 0xa7
```

#### Details

On my system (Ubuntu 18.04), VLC crashes when attempting to play certain media files. Launching from the command line yields some information.

```
$ vlc problematic_file.webm
VLC media player 3.0.8 Vetinari (revision 3.0.8-0-gf350b6b5a7)
[0000557f93cb1570] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
dbus[3681]: arguments to dbus_message_iter_append_basic() were incorrect, assertion "_dbus_check_is_valid_utf8 (*string_p)" failed in file ../../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 2754.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.

  D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Apparently I'm [not the first person this has happened to](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/8390). Using ffmpeg to strip out the global metadata resolved the crash.

```
$ ffmpeg -i problematic_file.webm -c copy -map_metadata -1 fixed.webm
```

Based on this, the obvious generalized solution seems to be to extract all metadata, validate it, sanitize it as necessary, and write it back. However, testing with the iconv utility indicated that the extracted (problematic) metadata was in fact valid UTF-8!

```
$ ffmpeg -i problematic_file.webm -f ffmetadata metadata.txt
$ iconv -f UTF-8 metadata.txt -o /dev/null; echo $?
0
```

Further testing indicated that the emojis identified above were the source of the problem.

Comment: See https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f508/index.htm…

Comment: @deceze Thanks! The resources I checked didn't specify the various raw encodings like that. Guess it's a dbus bug.

Comment: Please [file a bug against D-Bus](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/dbus/dbus/issues/new), or this will never be fixed. Include the full D-Bus backtrace from the assertion failure, which will mean you’ll need to install your distribution’s debug packages for D-Bus.

Comment: @PhilipWithnall Will do - might even submit a patch. Still not entirely sure dbus validation is what's at fault (VLC or some lib could be mangling something). Found the validation implementation (`_dbus_string_validate_utf8`) in [`dbus-string.c`](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/dbus/dbus/blob/dbus-1.12/dbus/dbus-string.c). Haven't had a chance to pick through it yet. My distro appears to be on [v1.12.2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/dbus), current is v1.12.16 (haven't diffed yet).

Comment: Great! Good luck! :)